# Legend display on mouse hover over region made using RegionPlot

Tags: regions, legending, labeling, dynamic

Is there a way to label a **region** plotted using `RegionPlot` automatically, i.e. for the legend to appear inside the region without having to specify coordinates?

Alternatively, is it possible to show the legend corresponding to a subregion when I hover the mouse on that region?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ClearAll[tBar, teXt]

teXt[impregs_, colors_, t_] := Text[Framed[Style[impregs[[t, 1, 1]], 16, Bold, 
     Opacity[1], Darker@colors[[t]]], Background -> None, FrameStyle -> None], 
   Mean[RandomPoint[impregs[[t]], 200]]];

tBar[regs_, colors_] := Dynamic[TogglerBar[Dynamic[n], 
    Table[i -> SwatchLegend[{colors[[i]]}, {Style[TraditionalForm[regs[[i]]], ## & @@ 
       If[MemberQ[n, i], {14, Bold}, 12], "Panel", Opacity[1], colors[[i]], 
        Background -> None]}, LegendMarkerSize -> 16], {i, 1, Length@regs}], 
    Appearance -> {"Horizontal", "Framed"}, Background -> None]];
```

**Example:**

```
regs = {x^2 < (y - 2)^3 + 1, 2 (y + 1)^2 + (x - 3)^2 <= 9, x + y <= -2};
impregs = ImplicitRegion[#, {{x, -6, 6}, {y, -6, 6}}] & /@ regs;
colors = ColorData[97] /@ Range[5];

Dynamic[RegionPlot[Evaluate[MapIndexed[Tooltip[#, #2[[1]]]&, regs]], {x, -6, 6}, {y, -6, 6},
  PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, {-6, 6}}, ImageSize -> 450, PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
  PlotLabel -> Mouseover[Invisible @ tBar[regs, colors], tBar[regs, colors]], 
  BoundaryStyle -> Thread[n -> Thickness[.01]],
  Epilog -> {teXt[impregs, colors, #] & /@ n}, 
  DisplayFunction -> (# /. Tooltip[p_, t_] :> Mouseover[p,
    {p, If[MemberQ[n, t], {}, teXt[impregs, colors, t]]}] &)], 
 Initialization :> {n := {}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @kglr. That is very elegant, indeed!